# Do not or Can not?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-usage, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

When I am thinking how to best explain my idea, I got the following doubt

> I **do not** understand why...
>
> I **can not** understand why...

I feel both sentence pattern give a same meaning. But again I feel, if they are equal why there are two ways, so that I feel these two should give two different meanings. But for me, I can not figure out what is the main difference of using ... do not ... and ... can not ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the context of *understand*, *cannot* and *do not* amount to much the same thing: *I cannot* points a little to the effort you have made to understand, but usually if you *don’t* understand something it is because you *can’t* understand it.

In other contexts, however, *cannot* and *do not* may mean quite different things.

> I cannot read Cicero *probably means that you don’t know enough Latin to read Cicero*.
>   I do not read Cicero *means you choose not to read Cicero—you probably find his works boring*.

You should not be disturbed by the fact that two expressions mean approximately the same thing. In fact, there are many more than two:

> I am unable to understand why.
>   I fail to understand why.
>   I am at a loss to understand why.
>   I cannot conceive why.
>   I have no idea why. ... *and so forth*.

There are many ways of saying practically everything. I am confident you can point to instances in your own language.